# $(window).width() is not able to work perfectly for size above 500px and below 500px

Tags: jquery

My code is as shown below:

```
if ($(window).width() > 500) {
    $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout").hover(function() {
        $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout .q-jyoti-info").css("display", "block");

    }, function() {
        $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout .q-jyoti-info").css("display", "none");

    });
}else if ($(window).width() <= 500) {
    $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout").hover(function() {
        $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-xzz").css("display", "block");

    }, function() {
        $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-xzz").css("display", "none");

    });
}
```

My Html code is as shown below:

```
<div class="q-team-layout">
                <div class="q-jyoti-layout">
                    <img class="q-team-images" src="../test/images/jyoti.png" alt="Los Angeles">
                    <div class="q-name">Jyotirmoy</div>
                    <div class="q-desig">CEO</div>
                    <div class="x1">
                        <span style="color:#ff363f;font-weight:bold;"> Jyoti </span>
                        <span style="color:#4d4d4d;"> CEO </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="q-jyoti-info">Lives in Gurgaon. <br/>Has spent 6 years in various multinational companies executing and ideating for new age projects.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="q-xzz">Lives in Gurgaon. <br/>Has spent 6 years in various multinational companies executing and ideating for new age projects.</div>
</div>
```

So basically what I want here is above 500px **.q-xzz** should not be there and below 500px **.q-jyoti-info** should not be there. But somehow this condition is not working perfectly for both mobile and web. Is there anything missing in this conditional statement?

Comment: You also have `screen.width` and `screen.height`. Else I would make it an `if` `else` statement, `if is above 500px` do this, `else` do that. Cuz you don't need an else if

Comment: What classes are added to the dom

Comment: *"not working perfectly"* is not a proper problem description and doesn't tell us much of value

Comment: No still it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Put the conditional inside the `hover()` to simplify

```
$("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout").hover(function() {
   var childSelector = $(window).width() > 500 ? '.q-jyoti-info' : '.q-xzz';
   $(this).find(childSelector).toggle();//does same as hide/show
});
```

Note that when you only provide one function argument in `hover()` it will be called for both events

Answer (score 0):

First of all place this in your css file, so when the html and css are parse in the browser the default value of the element is going to be hidden

**#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout .q-jyoti-info{
    
display:none

}**

Then add class in the css

**.show{
    
display:block

}**

After that you can use jQuery Methods 'addClass()' and 'removeClass()'

```
if ($(window).width() > 500) {    
            $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout").hover(function() {
                $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout .q-jyoti-info").addClass('show');

            }, function() {
                $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout .q-jyoti-info").removeClass('show');

            });
    }

     else {
            $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout").hover(function() {
                $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-xzz").addClass('show');

            }, function() {
                $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-xzz").removeClass('show');

            });
        }
```

Comment: your `.show` selector in css isn't specific enough to have priority over the other rule

Comment: so put !important at the end of the rule

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the jQuery not triggering at exactly 500px width, this is because `$(window).width()` does not account for the browsers scrollbar. There is no way to compensate for this because different browser have different scrollbar widths. However you could use `matchMedia`, which allows for the use of media queries in jQuery. However `matchMedia` is not supported in IE9 and under.

```
if(window.matchMedia('(min-width: 500px)').matches) {
  $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout").hover(function() {
    $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout .q-jyoti-info").addClass('show');
  }, function() {
    $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout .q-jyoti-info").removeClass('show');
  });
} else {
  $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-jyoti-layout").hover(function() {
     $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-xzz").css("display", "block");
   }, function() {
     $("#about-us .q-team .q-team-layout .q-xzz").css("display", "none");
   });
}
```

Comment: No, both .q-xzz and q-jyoti-info are not working in sync

Comment: It would be helpful to see your HTML and a bit more explanation as to what you are trying to achieve.